# PCB connector 0.05" pitch

Tags: pcb, identification, connector

I need to replace the white male plug. Can somebody tell me what it is called?

Note that this connector is inserted by pushing it vertically onto the board, it is *not* axially inserted like most Molex or JST connectors.
The pitch of the contacts seems to be 0.05" (or perhaps 1.25 mm), the width of the female receptacle on the board (outside width) is 4.19 mm. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[image: PCB connector]

Comment: Pretty sure I recognise the connector, but I'm not sure what it's called. Look through Molex's offerings, I think it was one of theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a parallel-mate, wire-to-board connector.

1.27 mm is not a standard pitch. It's either 1.2 or 1.3 mm.

I used [my connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=parallel_mate_w2b_conn&f=wire_parallel_mate_w2b_conn&fl=00000000000000000000000000000000-500-%7C1.2%7C2%7C%7C%7C) to identify it as possibly one of these:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- JST - ACH
- JST - ACHL
- JST - ADH
- Molex - Pico-EZmate
- TE - AmpSlim

Comment: Great answer, and you've made a very nice and useful tool!

Comment: Thank you for the kudos.

Comment: thank you so much Davide, grazie mille! I don't think it's a Pico_EZmate though, since the white male plug appears to have some kind of "roof" that extends beyond the connector, and the EZ doesn't have it.